# MySQL - INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY - 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I am going to be logging the IP addresses that my users log in with. To do this, I have a simple table with 3 columns: user, ip, time. time is the time at which they last logged in with that address.

When they log in, I want to insert a row into the database containing the IP they logged in with, and the time they logged in.

If a row with the same user AND same ip already exists, I just want to update the time. A more general question:

How can I INSERT a row, or UPDATE it if two (or more) of its columns are the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to create composite unique key `user + ip` and use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO tbl (user, ip, `time`) VALUES (1, '1.2.3.4', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `time` = NOW()
```

To create index use something like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_user_ip ON tbl (user, ip)
```

Comment: @DrAgonmoray: have you heard of just composite keys or unique keys?

Comment: I've heard of unique, but I never knew you could assign a single key to multiple columns. Fantastic, thanks!